# Solving for all coefficients of powers of x given a equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given a equation of following:

$$
 xa_{1}+x^2a_{2}+x^3a_{3}+x^4a_{4}+x^5a_{5}+......=0
$$
$\forall x>0$

I want to prove that $a_i=0 \forall i\ge1$

I am not sure if this is true.

Comment: since $\mathbb{R}[x]$  is a vector space with that basis, plus $x^0$, it's definitely true (definition of linear indipendence) IF the equation ends. If that's a series (if that sum can be infinite) well I might have to think about it

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 It has infinitely many terms(with cardinality equal to that of $\mathbb{N}$)

Answer (score 1):

Take the $n$th derivative and evaluate at 0. This is equal to a positive multiple of $a_n$ and also equal to 0. To see that this is valid, note that the function is also equal to 0 when $x=0$ because this is true for every partial sum.

Comment: $x>0$ so x cant be zero.

Comment: See reasoning above for why plugging in 0 is valid. The function is 0 at $x=0$.